# Extract value demited by delimiter after a particular word

Tags: java, regex, match

Suppose a have a main string something like:
"The last prices are Samsung(100.59), Nokia(35.23), Apple(199.34)".
Is there any method to extract the value from this String by sending the names?

public Double getValue(String name);

So the getValue("Nokia") will return 35.23 and getValue(Apple) will return 199.34.

Comment: In API, No. You've write your own logic.

Comment: what is wrong with writing your own based upon `String.indexOf ("Nokia")`

Comment: `\w\(\d+(\.\d+)?\)` You could try out this regex to get the name with value and then `split` it up on parentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with regex

```
public Double getValue(String name){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=" + name + "\\()\\d+\\.\\d+(?=\\))");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("<your matcher string>");
    m.find();
    return Double.parseDouble(m.group());
}
```

Comment: just an improvement, better to put `Pattern.compile("(?<=" + name + "\\()\\d+\\.\\d+(?=\\))")` outside of method.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something which will work in your case

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "The last prices are Samsung(100.59), Nokia(35.23), Apple(199.34)";
    System.out.println(getValue(s, "Samsung"));
    System.out.println(getValue(s, "Nokia"));
    System.out.println(getValue(s, "Apple"));
}

private static String getValue(String text, String valueOf) {
    int fromIndex = text.indexOf(valueOf);
    int start = text.indexOf("(", fromIndex);
    int end = text.indexOf(")", fromIndex);
    return text.substring(start + 1, end);
}
```